# How can I make my HTML model data display in a <textarea> as it would in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My code returns HTML data from ASP.NET as a response from an action method.

I am displaying this in a `<textarea>` element.

```
    <textarea style="width: 85rem; height: 15rem;"
              ng-disabled=true
              ng-model="access.response"></textarea>
```

However when it displays I see the actual HTML.

How can I make it so the information displayed in the textbox or some other way is the same as in my browser window? Note that I do not want to edit the data but I would like the scrollbar type feature.

Comment: Append the markup to a `<div>` instead of a `<textarea>`?

Comment: If you're using `jQuery` to append markup, be careful to use the `html()` method instead of `text()`. And as @FrédéricHamidi said, append content to a div (for instance), and then you can set `contenteditable="true"` attribute on it.

Comment: @Nicolae - I'm not using jQuery. Thanks

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - How can I append to a <div>. Do you mean with using {{ }} ?  - Would this then show as in a browser or would I see the HTML (not wanted)

Comment: `textarea` is for displaying plain text http://developers.whatwg.org/the-button-element.html#the-textarea-element and not for rendering html. if you want to render html from the server, take a look https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml directive and familiarize yourself with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is correct to say that you cannot display it in a `textarea`, but you can't use a simple `div` neither to display the parsed HTML.

Take a look at this Plunkr --> http://plnkr.co/edit/ld4Nte2KKIbgMkIWnRcP

You have to make use of the `$sce` service and the `ng-bind-html` directive, like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="SimpleCtrl"> 

        <!-- This will be parsed as HTML-->
        <div ng-bind-html="to_trusted(someCode)"></div>

        <!-- This will not -->
        <div>{{someCode}}</div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it with `textarea`.

If you want editable HTML content, consider this:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: It's response data so it should not be editable. Will your suggestion show raw HTML or will it change it to look like in a browser?

Comment: Just use `ng-bind-html` if you want to show html (see answer below). Don't forget add `ngSanitize` as dependency to your application.