# Angular bootstrap tabs- refreshing a tab with a new html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using tabs of angular bootstrap ui. I have overriden the tabs directive so as to perform lazy loading of data Plunkr link for the same : http://plnkr.co/edit/VABthzUwp50QpS16Gwuy?p=preview

The lazy loading works perfectly fine.I have a requirement where in the tab should get reloaded with a different html on clicking of a button.

For ex, say I have a tab which renders tab1.htm. This tab1.htm has a button on click of that button I want to render a different html in the same tab.

I tried changing the template-url of the div for tab1,however I am not able to reload the current tab with the new url

Answer (score 0):

Your Plunkr use a strongly outdated version of Angular, which doesn't support the new `$sce` service to be used with `ng-bind-html`

Also, it ha some serious issues with CSS that I'm not gonna fix, so I will point you in the right direction instead.

In this answer ([How can I make my HTML model data display in a <textarea> as it would in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301399/how-can-i-make-my-html-model-data-display-in-a-textarea-as-it-would-in-a-brows/24301908#24301908)) you can find how to "inject" HTML into your page using a modern AngularJS version (1.2.0 or higher).

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ld4Nte2KKIbgMkIWnRcP

If you really want to stick with `1.0.8`, you will have to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` which is pretty straight-forward:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{html_code}}"></div>
```

And in some controller:

```
$scope.html_code = "<h1>Some fancy HTML code</h1>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an option for one of the tabs to present "conditional data".

There is a very simple way to set this up using an ng-view + template as the container for your tab.

First set up a basic ng-view as such:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Than connect it via your app config...

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/tab2', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab2.html',
        controller: 'tab2'
    }).
```

Finally, you need to add a "conditional load" to the route provider. The link syntax will be site/module?conditional (or whatever you want with the question mark).

See the documentation here and search for $location.search(). Simple link the button to the conditional url which represents the conditional data for your tab.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Note: Once you have retrieved the conditional url with $location.search()[""], just concatenate it to a url string

```
templateUrl: 'templates/tab2' + searchObject["v"] +'.html',
```

in order to route correctly. If no conditional statement is presented, the url will route to the default template or html file as it usually does.

tl;dr:
1) Create a config file with $routeProvider setup
2) Create a conditional link to a template with your tab's data.
3) Link your button to that link

Comment: I fixed the problem by setting the  $scope.$parent.$parent.templateUrl= /home/index.htm. Updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VABthzUwp50QpS16Gwuy?p=preview. Now my question is can we pass parameters to the url? if so how can we retrieve the parameters in the tabs